# Exit source view in inline mode

Tags: jodit

Using inline mode with the following config, when switching to `source` view, the toolbar does not appear any longer on selection. How does one exit the source view?

```
export const joditConfig = {
  inline: true,
  toolbar: false,
  toolbarInline: true,
  toolbarInlineForSelection: true,
  popup: {
    selection: Jodit.atom([
      'bold',
      'italic',
      'ul',
      'ol',
      'paragraph',
      'table',
      'link',
      'spellcheck',
      'source'
    ])
  },
  showXPathInStatusbar: false,
  showCharsCounter: false,
  showWordsCounter: false,
  showPlaceholder: false
}
```

I expected an `exit source` button would be available somewhere.